# Как сделать, чтобы xcode парсил json при отсутствии интернет-подключения?

Tags: xcode, ios, json, objective-c, синтаксический-анализ

Как сделать, чтобы xcode парсил json при отсутствии интернет-подключения? Где хранить? Я паршу из php файла и с интернетом все работает нормально.

Comment: json берется с удоленного сервера и парсится, чтобы он парсился и когда девайс не подключен к инету, нужно где-то хранить старую его загрузку. вот я не знаю где и как это сделать

Comment: Дык пождите, вы когда его качаете в чем проблемма его гденить сохранить?

Answer (score 1):

Во время работающего инета сохрани JSON. Нашел у себя такой кусок:

```
- (void)writeJsonToFile
{
    //applications Documents dirctory path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //live json data url
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://path-to-live-file.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //attempt to download live data
    if (urlData)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
    //copy data from initial package into the applications Documents folder
    else
    {
        //file to write to
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];

        //file to copy from
        NSString *json = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"html/data" ];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        //write file to device
        [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну мы с ребятами, качаем json`чик мапим его в CoreData сохраняем контекст, и больше он нам не нужен.

Comment: а если данные меняются во время работы приложения, вы меняете сразу в CoreData или отправляете на серв, скачиваете json и снова мапите?

Comment: ну это очень сильно зависит от задачи. Вообще все данные беруться из ManagerObjectContext`а (который их сохраняет, когда приложение сварачивается и читает заного из базы, когда разварачивается). И да если сервису нужна оперативная информация о клиенте, то данные просто переводятся в json и отправляются на сервер. И если сервер что-то кидает они тут же мапятся на Контекст. JSON  Это просто сериализация объекта чтоб ее передать и принять. Работаем конечто же с данными из контекста. Если же вообще нужна оперативная информация как в играх используем не REST интерфейс а SOAP или простой  WebSocket

Comment: спасибо, все достаточно понятно)

Answer (score -1):

Используйте [AFNetwoking](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/index.html) и этой библиотеки есть встроенные механизмы кеширования. [FAQ](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ)

Comment: а можно сделать это без использования посторонних фрэймов?

Comment: Можно, используйте CFNetwork, CFNetwork Programming Guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html